# Downloading image from canvas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, canvas

http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

click save, then click the download button.
I am trying to make it download the image and also rename it a name, in my code it is 'myimage' I appreciate any help you can give me, thanks!

Error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/29/10007129/html/taffatech/saveme.php:2) in /home/content/29/10007129/html/taffatech/saveme.php on line 4

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/29/10007129/html/taffatech/saveme.php:2) in /home/content/29/10007129/html/taffatech/saveme.php on line 7
```

Code for php:

```
<?php
    # we are a PNG image
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    # we are an attachment (eg download), and we have a name
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_POST['name'] .'"');

    #capture, replace any spaces w/ plusses, and decode
    $encoded = $_POST['imgdata'];
    $encoded = str_replace(' ', '+', $encoded);
    $decoded = base64_decode($encoded);

    #write decoded data
    echo $decoded;
?>
```

js button:

```
$("#download").click(function() {
var cs = new CanvasSaver('http://taffatech.com/saveme.php');

cs.savePNG(canvas, 'myimage');
});
```

save function js:

```
function CanvasSaver(url) {

    this.url = url;

    this.savePNG = function(canvas, fname) {
        if(!canvas || !url) return;
        fname = fname || 'picture';

        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();

        var dataInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("name", 'imgdata') ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);
        dataInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

        var nameInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("name", 'name') ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("value", fname + '.png');

        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.action = url;
        myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
        myForm.appendChild(nameInput);



    document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
    myForm.submit() ;
    document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
};
```

}

Thanks! If you need anymore info just ask!

Comment: Can you confirm you don't have any whitespace at the start of `saveme.php`?

Comment: Indeed, based on the hexdump, it looks like there's a newline character preceding your initial `<?php`.

Comment: Thanks guys the newline was the issue, didn't know lines caused an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the first line on the php,you can not have a blank line at the start of the php file. Thanks all.